# No post request after submitting a form when I want to download a PDF

Tags: python, selenium, urllib2

I'm writing a script to download a pdf automatically.
Firstly, I open the url manually, it will redirect to a login website.
and I type my username and password, and click "submit".
Then download will start directly.
During this procedure, I check the firebug, I find there is no post while I click "submit".

I'm not familiar with this behavior, that means the pdf(300K) is saved before I submit?
If there is no post, then I must use some tool like selenium to simulate this "click"?

Comment: Is there any other request visible after you click the submit button (it doesn't have to be a POST)?

Comment: no, I can't see any message.
Just find the download start directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no request at all, or a GET request? I suspect there is a GET request. In that case, did you turn `Persist` on in Firebug's Net tab? Possibly the POST request was hidden after redirects.

Comment: No, I've turned it on. But I can't see any new message after I type in the user name , password and click submit.
Is it possible the download is already finished and saved in some place, after I click submit, it will trigger some js function ?

Comment: It is possible, but it would be insecure and not common. I'd definitely check if there isn't a problem with Firebug or caching or something.

Comment: But I did find no post or get with firebug.How can I figure out if there is anything wrong .